# Watched questions contrast is really poor on our site

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, site-design

So Stack Exchange got new colors, and there’s a [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393939/190917) Q&A about it, but this issue seems to be specific to our site: questions with watched tags get a color highlight, but the contrast between it and regular questions is quite slight, so those questions don’t actually stand out the way they should:

[image: Image from RPG.SE main page showing several questions, two with watched tags and three without, showing the limited contrast between the two]

This hadn’t been mentioned on the Meta.SE Q&A because most sites don’t have this problem: their contrast is greater:

[image: Image from Meta.SE main page showing three questions, one with a watched tag, to show the greater contrast]

The cause here is pretty clear, too: all sites use `--yellow-100` for this highlight color, but our site uses a different background color for regular questions that is much more yellow-ish (`#FFFDF7`) and thus much closer to `--yellow-100` than the white (`#FFFFFF`) used on most sites. We need either a custom `--yellow-100` (and presumably customizations to the other `--yellow-###` colors to correspond appropriately), or we need a custom rule that doesn’t use `--yellow-100` for these questions.

([Cross-posted this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394027/190917) to the new color Q&A on Meta.SE for visibility.)

Comment: It seems the problem is extremely endemic, as we use a yellow base color... might a swap to **white** highlighting for us specifically be an option?

Comment: @Trish At a guess, that would look odd and probably won’t have the desired contrast either. (My speculation: since our background seems about halfway between white and `yellow-100`, white won’t be any farther away from it than `yellow-100` is.)